# Thinking Sphinx delta index only updated when in console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

This has been asked several times, but I found no solution in existing questions.

Documents in the core index can be found, but documents in the delta cannot be found.

- I have a boolean delta attribute in the database that defaults to true. I see that all documents in the core currently have delta=0 and all new have delta=1.
- I have `set_property :delta => true` in document.rb
- The delta index is in the config file and there are delta index files on my hard drive.
- I have rebuilt, reindexed and restarted the server.
- I see no indexer output in my logfile when i create a new document via the web, **BUT:**

**It works fine when I create the documents in the console** with `User.first.documents.create(same_params_as_on_web)`. However, I use the same command in my controller: `@document = current_user.documents.create(params[:document])`

After I create a document in the console and the delta indexer runs automatically, the other documents created via the web also get included.

Any idea, why the indexer might not get triggered when called via the web, but is in the console?

I am useing thinking-sphinx (2.0.5) with rails (3.2.1) via apache/passenger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kindly refer myself to the Common Issues page, section Running Delta Indexing with Passenger
http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/common_issues.html#passenger

Look what path the searchd is on with `which searchd`

And then set the bin_path option in your config/sphinx.yml file accordingly:

```
production:
  bin_path: '/usr/local/bin'
```